# Is there some fully configured Spring Wicket Hibernate archetype including Annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, wicket

I guess tons of people asked this questions, but as of now, I haven't found a sufficient answer:
I'm a newbie to Java-WebApp-Development. I'm quite used to work with a fully configured Spring-Wicket-Hibernate environment at work. Though I am still not able to set up such an project on my own.

I tried using http://blog.iprofs.nl/2011/02/15/a-maven-quickstart-on-wicket-spring-and-hibernate/, but still I have huge problems solving the simplest tasks (such as implementing a count(*)-Method in the generic Dao).
Although I know I *should* dive deeper into those frameworks I know this won't be possible due to my little spare time. Currently I'm diving into Wicket, but this is just one out of 3 frameworks I gonna need to learn to configure and use.

Though this is kind of naiv, I'm hoping out there might be *the* maven-archetype for folks like me: A fully configured Spring-Wicket-Hibernate-Annotated maven-project which I can modify and learn how to walk on my own.

Is there something out there that might satisfy my need? I'm not talking necessarily of maven-archetype, a well written tutorial will do as well.

Right now I'm really frustated about all those little problems which hold me back from beginning to develop my first WebApp.

Best regards,
Franz

Answer (score 10):

I put this together, hope it helps

[wicket-spring-hibernate](https://github.com/robobario/wicket-spring-hibernate)

I started from the wicket quickstart so you have mvn:jetty-run which will start the application on port 9005